# Collecting facebook user-id from website visitors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, tracking, identification

Is there any way to take the facebook user-id of a website visitor and save the user-id to a text file to keep track of visitors. I know there is some ways using Facebooks API, but it seems like the user have to give permission, and that is not what we want. So any way to save the facebook user-id of a website visitor without any user interaction?

Comment: without user giving permission, you cannot. If this was a Facebook application, it is a different case. Then there is a workaround to parse the signed_request. What you can do is at least have a like button in your web site. You can keep track of the users who likes your web page.

Comment: So i can keep track of who hit the like button, but not who is presented with the app?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you can't. This would be a huge privacy/security issue IMO. You need explicit permission from the user to get his ID on your own website.